# Alternative to copy file content in a dictionary in YAML

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml

I have a text file similar like this

```
[Kingdom]
Animal=rabbit
Species=mammal

[Rabbit]
Name=Alex
```

So, I just copy the file into a dictionary using `MasterDict = config.__dict__['_sections'].copy()`

How can I use the same function with YAML file. I converted the same text file into YAML like this,

```
default:
  Animal : rabbit
  Species : Mammal

rabbit:
  Name:Alex
```

Comment: Your YAML is invalid. `=` is not a special character. Also, you have to indent the two lines after `default:` more to make them children of that node.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to load the file to get a dictionary:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

with open('in.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)
print(data)
```

prints:

```
{'default': {'Animal': 'rabbit', 'Species': 'Mammal'}, 'rabbit': 'Name:Alex'}
```